# Selecting data structure for ordered set of elements with fast traversal of elements in predefined order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, heap

Which data structure allows following:

1. store ordered (sorted by some criteria) set of elements;
2. allows traverse of elements in this predefined order with minimal algorithmic complexity;
3. insertion new elements or deletion of existing elements desired with minimal algorithmic complexity;
4. storing elements in non-continuous (scattered) memory region.

At first look something like red-black tree might be an option, or xfast-tree, but I looking for relatively simpler algorithm. I will glad to see you suggestions.

Comment: Popular programming languages like C++, Java use RB trees for implementing these type of data structures. You could use their library directly. Do you want to implement them yourselves? RB trees are as simple as it could get for the above requirements. Other option is AVL tree.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to go for some [self-balancing search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) solution. Wikipedia lists several implementations. You already mentioned red-black tree. There is also avl-tree.

If you cannot use a high performance library for this, and you have to implement it yourself, you could also look into a self-implemented [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). Although this data structure was intended to deal with slower disk storage, there is no reason why it could not be used with memory-only storage.

The advantage of [B trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and B+ trees is that you can play with the block size to tune performance. Compared to other choices, these trees do not need the "rotation" action. Instead they split and join block-nodes. A B+ tree has as additional advantage that traversal of the data in sorted order is very simple, as it comes down to traversing a linked (block) list.